# std::array iterator range without template?

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator

With C arrays, it is fairly easy to write code that takes arrays of any size:

```
void func( T* itBegin, T* itEnd );

void main() {
    T arr1[1];
    func( std::begin(arr1), std::end(arr1) );
    T arr2[2];
    func( std::begin(arr2), std::end(arr2) );
}
```

How can I do that with std::arrays?

```
void func( ??? itBegin, ??? itEnd );

void main() {
    std::array<T,1> arr1;
    func( std::begin(arr1), std::end(arr1) );
    std::array<T,2> arr2;
    func( std::begin(arr2), std::end(arr2) );
}
```

The problem is that, in MSVC 2010, `std::array<T,N>::iterator` is different for different `N`. Is this a bug in MSVC 2010? If not, what is the rationale of this design? Yes, I could get pointers from the std::array and pass them instead of iterators, but isn't that unnecessarily ugly?

BTW, `boost::array<T,N>::iterator` are the same for all `N`.

Comment: What do you mean by "without template"?

Comment: `void func( T* itBegin, T* itEnd )` is already a templated function, so I cannot se how can you comply with that "without template" requirement.

Comment: @Gorpik: Well, no, it isn't templated. It just uses a type with the unfortunate name `T`. See `main`, which also uses `T` and cannot be templated.

Answer (score 4):

```
template <class I>
void func(I begin, I end)
{
    for (auto x = begin; x != end; ++x)
        something_with(*x);
}
```

Define them genericly as a type parameter, and then just use them as if they were pointers.  Anything that behaves pointer-like will compile, things that don't, won't.

Pointer-like things include normal pointers, as well as standard library iterators, and anything else that defines `operator=`, `operator*` and `operator++`.

Doing it this way and as you will only ever use matching pairs of begin/end iterator ranges from the same `array<N>`, then it doesn't matter if `array<N>::iterator` is a different type to `array<M>::iterator`.

Comment: I know it is easy with a template. But virtual functions, for example, cannot be templates, and templates have to be defined in the header. There is no technical reason why a template is needed.

Comment: @Arno: Type parameters is the C++ idiom for passing iterators.  If you're not comfortable with templates, you are going to be miserable using the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the standard doesn't require that different sized `std::array` have the same type of iterator; having a different type for `std::array<int, 1>` and `std::array<int, 2>` seems legal (although one might have some opinions with regards to the quality of the implementation).

If this is a problem, you can either use a C style array, or use pointers:

```
func( &arr1[0], &arr1[0] + arr1.size() );
```

Neither solution is ideal, but they're the best I can offer.

Comment: `&*begin(arr1), &*end(arr1)` ? Might look bizarre at first glance, but should be a common technique with iterators, smart pointers.

Comment: Well, it only works if the underlying memory block is contiguous and compact, which it is for array and vector, but of course not in general.

Comment: @Arno: The longer syntax in the answer also requires that.

Comment: @Arno Yes, but his problem is uniquely with `std::array`.  (Of course, if you're going to do this a lot, I'd suggest an overloaded `begin` and `end`, which do this for an `std::array`, and forward to `std::begin` and `std::end` for anything else.)

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class I>
void func(I begin, I end);
```